# Convert mongo Shell script to java

Tags: java, mongodb

I need to convert the following Mongo Shell query to Java query using BasicDBObject.

```
db.transactions.find(
    {
        "$or":[
            { 
               "originUser._id": ObjectId("56c5b433fbea2f2b96e06148"),
               "targetUser._id": ObjectId("56c5b433fbea2f2b96e06149")
            },         
            {
               "originUser._id": ObjectId("56c5b433fbea2f2b96e06149"),
               "targetUser._id": ObjectId("56c5b433fbea2f2b96e06148")
            }
       ]
   }
);
```

What I have tried is:

```
BasicDBObject clause1 = new BasicDBObject("originUser._id", userId).append("targetUser._id ", transactionQuery.getUserId());
BasicDBObject clause2 = new BasicDBObject("originUser._id", transactionQuery.getUserId()).append("targetUser._id ", userId);
BasicDBObject or_conditions[]={clause1,clause2};
query.append("$or", or_conditions);
```

Result to be shown:
        Object 1:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55b22649cd6a900b96bb040a"),
    "originUser" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("56c5b433fbea2f2b96e06149"),
        "firstName" : "Mark",
        "lastName" : "Ti",
    },
    "targetUser" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("56c5b433fbea2f2b96e06148"),
        "firstName" : "John",
        "lastName" : "Doe",
    },
}
```

Object 2:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55b22649cd6a900b96bb040b"),
    "originType" : "NFC",
    "originUser" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("56c5b433fbea2f2b96e06148"),
        "firstName" : "John",
        "lastName" : "Doe",
    },
    "targetUser" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("56c5b433fbea2f2b96e06149"),
        "firstName" : "Mark",
        "lastName" : "Ti",
    },
}
```

Query string in java:

```
{ "$or" : [ { "originUser._id" : { "$oid" : "56c5b433fbea2f2b96e06148"} , "targetUser._id " : { "$oid" : "56c5b433fbea2f2b96e06149"}} , { "originUser._id" : { "$oid" : "56c5b433fbea2f2b96e06149"} , "targetUser._id " : { "$oid" : "56c5b433fbea2f2b96e06148"}}]}
```

This result is showed when i run the query for shell script but doesnt return any result when i run the query from java.

Kindly help

Comment: And what is the problem you're facing?

Comment: Java returns no response where as in mongo shell script the response is returned. There are no errors but still the result is empty in java and not in shell script

Comment: Print toString of query...

Comment: { "$or" : [ { "originUser._id" : { "$oid" : "56c5b433fbea2f2b96e06148"} , "targetUser._id " : { "$oid" : "56c5b433fbea2f2b96e06149"}} , { "originUser._id" : { "$oid" : "56c5b433fbea2f2b96e06149"} , "targetUser._id " : { "$oid" : "56c5b433fbea2f2b96e06148"}}]}

Comment: just to make sure you pass the right args : your userId variables are org.bson.types.ObjectId right ?

Comment: @YairHarel: Yes they are.